# how to key in rows of data, which are then appended to a csv database

Tags: python, list, csv, append, writer

I'm not sure if this can just be done directly or if the csv has to be read in and converted to a list first e.g.

```
import csv
opened_file = open('example.csv')
read_file = reader(opened_file)
examlist = list(opened_file)
```

Using example data, instead of input for simplicity. Then I can append a row to the list,

```
rows = [ ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],  ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]
examlist.append(rows)
```

Then I have a list comprised of the original csv, plus the 2 rows I wanted to add.  But when writing it back to the example.csv

```
with open('example.csv', 'w') as of:
    of.write(examp)
```

It won't accept it because the csv is str.

Do I just convert it back to as string and add it?  Is the wrong way of going about the process?  It feels really wrong but I'm very inexperienced and not sure of everything.

Comment: Why are you using CSV as a database in the first place?

Comment: Should `examlist = list(opened_file)` be `examlist = list(read_file)` ? Maybe `examlist.append(rows)` should be `examlist.extend(rows)`. When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: use the CSV writer or pandas CSV writer. You are trying to use the normal text file writer.